# Drawing the region $A$ with inequality $|s_1| + |s_2| \leq 1$

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

Currently I have trouble understanding this region $A = \{(s_1, s_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : |s_1| + |s_2| \leq 1\}$, since I do not really know how to transform the inequality $|s_1| + |s_2| \leq 1$. Is there a general receipt how to rearrange these kind of equalites to determine the bounds of $s_1$ and $s_2$?

Comment: Hint: Use the definition of absolute value

Comment: I would try setting $s_1$ equal to some numbers and seeing if you can figure out the pattern. For instance, at $s_1  = 0$, what can $s_2$ be?

Comment: Alternatively, if you can figure out how it looks for $s_1\geq 0$ and $s_2 \geq 0$, then you will be able to just mirror that across each axis (I guess this is related to the comment about using the definition of absolute value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally when you face an absolute value, try to break its domain to regions where it is definitely positive or definitely negative. For this case consider four cases

$$\begin{cases}s_1+s_2\le1&s_1\ge0,s_2\ge0 \\-s_1+s_2\le1 &s_1<0,s_2\ge0 \\ s_1-s_2\le1&s_1\ge0,s_2<0 \\-s_1-s_2\le1 &s_1<0,s_2<0\end{cases}$$

after ploting each of these regions, you get this diamond shape. It's actually $l_1$-norm ball is $\mathbb{R}^2$.

[image]

here is a more detailed figure that helps you figure out what is happening.

[image]